# Get Codename from property and pass as a variable

Tags: excel, vba

I have a function that takes a sheetname as a parameter like

```
Sub do_things(sheetCodeName as Variant)
      sheetCodeName.Cells(1,1) = "Hello"
End Sub
```

I want to be able to get the codename of a given sheet using something like ActiveSheet.Codename and pass that as the codename parameter to my do_things subroutine. However, I get

> Run-Time error '424' Object Required.

This seems to be because ActiveSheet.Codename is a string while actually typing the codename in the subroutine call passes it as a worksheet.

Is there a way for me to gather the codename of a sheet and pass it to my do_things sub without having to manually type it?

Comment: Why not just pass a `Worksheet` variable? You can pass `ActiveSheet` directly if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simpler solution is just to pass a `Worksheet` object:

```
Sub do_things(ByVal ws As Worksheet)
      ws.Cells(1,1).Value = "Hello"
End Sub
```

You can just pass the `ActiveSheet` directly if needed. Trying to use the `.CodeName` is unnecessary.

Answer (score -1):

You could just pass the ActiveSheet, but if you can't do that for some reason you can change your sub:

```
Sub do_things(sheetCodeName as Variant)
      Worksheets(sheetCodeName).Cells(1,1) = "Hello"
End Sub
```

It doesn't work now because the string is not an object.

Comment: I agree with you that I would pass the worksheet (as stated in my first sentence). I was letting the OP know why it wasn't working also.

Comment: Not my downvote, but I'm guessing it's because a sheet code name is not always the same as the regular sheet name.